# Is it possible to listen to DragEvent and PointerEvents together?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, pointer-events

I have noticed that while listening to both drag events and pointer events, when drag starts, the pointer events are not caught.

```
<div id="canvas" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" ondragover="dragOver(event)" ondragend="dragEnd(event)" onpointerdown="pointerDown(event)" onpointermove="pointerMove(event)" onpointerup="pointerUp(event)"> 
  Drag Me 
</div>
```

I am hacking it by creating a pointer event from the drag event and dispatching it. Is there a better way of doing this?
https://jsfiddle.net/Souymodip/mvufyp70/177/